# Are there any HTML elements I could use as an "ID" element?

Tags: html, evernote

I'm using Evernote to sync data with my app, but I need the notes and their media items on Evernote to have an ID the same as the syncID held within my app, to match data with it's sync'd counterpart. To do this, I want to add a tag in the HTML which contains my syncID. Is there a tag I could use for something like this? Something for an 'id' function, or other custom function?

EDIT:

Example. Let's say the evernote note is like so:

```
<en-note>This is a note</en-note>
```

But I want to find out the ID of this note, to see if my app contains it or not. So ideally I'd have something like this:

```
<noteID="vdsijfewo329ds"><en-note>This is a note</en-note></noteID>
```

Or something similar, to help me find out which note this matches inside my app. Is this possible?

EDIT: Evernote disallows use of the data- attribute. So this:

```
<span data-syncID="fdshfiewo">
```

Would not be allowed.

Comment: .................. what?

Comment: Updated with example.

Comment: it's difficult to understand what your "my app" context is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**option 1** (general usage, not supported by Evernote today) you could use [HTML5 data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.dataset)

```
<span data-nodeID="vdsijfewo329ds"><en-note>This is a note</en-note></span>
```

**option 2** you could try `<figure>` - `<figcaption>` HTML5 pair:

```
<figure>
  <en-note>This is a note</en-note>
  <figcaption style="display: none">vdsijfewo329ds</figcaption>
</figure>
```

**option 3** class attribute (this was the reason data-* attributes were created, this could be the last resort option

```
<span class="en-note vdsijfewo329ds"><en-note>This is a note</en-note></span>
```

Comment: And using data-noteID, which I presume is something you just made up and could say anything, would be fine? EDIT - from reading the page you linked, i presume anything can go after `data-`, correct?

Comment: `data-*` is general multipurpose attributes (see the link), so yes, it would be "fine" (HTML5 standard)

Comment: Ah, it seems Evernote disallows use of the data attribute. Would there be any other way of doing something similar?